# How ObjectiveC mutableCopy work in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-plot

I am new in Swift and iOS development in general. Recently I was trying to use Swift to write an iOS app that uses CorePlot (which is written in ObjectiveC). I tried to rewrite a CorePlot iOS sample code (found in http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2) in Swift. There is a line like this in the sample objectiveC:

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplLineStyle = [aaplPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
aaplLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
```

that I tried to rewrite like this:

```
var lineStyle = aaplPlot.dataLineStyle.mutableCopy();
lineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
```

The problem is I get a compile error in my Swift version of code saying

```
"cannot assign to 'lineColor' in 'lineStyle'".
```

I also got a warning saying that

```
"variable lineStyle inferred to have type 'AnyObject', which may be unexpected"
```

**`'applePlot'`**, by the way, is of type CPTLineStyle defined like this in ObjectiveC:

```
@interface CPTLineStyle : NSObject<NSCoding, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGLineCap lineCap;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGLineJoin lineJoin;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat miterLimit;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat lineWidth;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *dashPattern;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat patternPhase;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CPTColor *lineColor;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CPTFill *lineFill;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CPTGradient *lineGradient;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = isOpaque) BOOL opaque;

/// @name Factory Methods
/// @{
+(instancetype)lineStyle;
/// @}

/// @name Drawing
/// @{
-(void)setLineStyleInContext:(CGContextRef)context;
-(void)strokePathInContext:(CGContextRef)context;
-(void)strokeRect:(CGRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context;
/// @}

@end
```

Can any body tell me if I was doing something wrong? How do I rewrite that lines of code in swift correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `mutableCopy` returns an AnyObject. An AnyObject has no properties, so you can't assign into a property of it. You need to cast this to a CPTMutableLineStyle.

```
var lineStyle = aaplPlot.dataLineStyle.mutableCopy() as CPTMutableLineStyle
lineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
```

Comment: Thanks again matt. I found it eventually so I deleted my previous comment asking where CPTMutableLineStyle because I have not seen your comment answering it.